# SQL needs to be revised

Tags: sql, databricks

I need to pull two columns from different tables with a Date column. See code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dates,
    COUNT(cocom) as LOR_Received,
    COUNT(Case)  as Cases_Asgn

FROM
    jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.dimdate dd
    --LEFT JOIN jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.dimdate dd ON dd.dates = lor.LOR_Receipt_Dt
    LEFT JOIN jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.cases_asgn asg ON asg.Caseasgn_Dt = dd.dates
    LEFT JOIN jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.lor_rcv lor ON lor.LOR_Receipt_Dt = dd.dates

WHERE
    dates = '4/27/2023'

GROUP BY
    dates
```

It's giving me the wrong results. See attached image. The number for Cases_asgn is supposed to be 18 and 10

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT DISTINCT` here? You're already using `GROUP BY` so it's either going to do absolutely nothing, or unintentionally hide rows.

Comment: So what should I do to get the correct results I said I needed?

Comment: No idea - you haven't shown us your source tables or data. We aren't psychic.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and the result you are trying to achieve - all as editable text rather than images. Also, it would help if you prefixed all the columns in your SQL with the appropriate table alias

Comment: One way to debug this might be to remove the grouping - you can get a "detail" view that has the individual records that are being counted. Then you can verify if that is correct, or if not more easily see what is not as expected.

Comment: The reason you are getting wrong results is because your tables are not 1:1 and so your counts are count of records of the result-set AFTER the tables are joined. What you want instead is a count for that date on each table FIRST and then to have that result joined. Consider getting your count-by-date in a subquery for each table, and then joining those subqueries togethers to get your final result.

Comment: So I verified that records are correct. How can get a count of each of the two columns by grouping by a date colum?.

Comment: @JNevill can you provide a sample query?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

You want to get a count of dates for each table in a subquery, and then join on the result. The reason you need to do this is that your tables have multiple records for each date (presumably), so joining before aggregating is going to generate an interim result set (for each date) of `<table 1 record count> x <table 2 record count> x <table 3 record count>`. Counting those records yields a much higher number than you expect.

Instead:

```
SELECT
    dd.dates,
    LOR_Received,
    Cases_Asgn    
FROM
    jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.dimdate dd
    --LEFT JOIN jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.dimdate dd ON dd.dates = lor.LOR_Receipt_Dt
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Caseasgn_Dt, count(*) as Cases_Asgn FROM jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.cases_asgn asg GROUP BY Caseasgn_Dt) asg ON asg.Caseasgn_Dt = dd.dates
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT LOR_Receipt_dt, count(*) as LOR_Received FROM jup_nipo_analytics_fms_workspace.lor_rcv GROUP BY LOR_Receipt_dt) lor ON lor.LOR_Receipt_Dt = dd.dates    
WHERE
    dates = '4/27/2023'
```

Comment: The code is giving me an error: Unable to fetch tables of db default

Comment: That's just because I fat-fingered a table name. I've updated the answer. Double check my sql before submitting though as I'm king at fat-fingering.